# How to add quotation marks to fractions?

Tags: punctuation, fractions

As the title says I want to add quotation marks around a fraction in `\displaystyle` mode. My first try looks very unnatural, as you can see

```
^{``}\frac{1}{0^-}^"
```

The problem is with the first quotation mark: how do I put it at the same height as the second one?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following minimal example provides `\mathquotes{<stuff>}` that puts quotes around `<stuff>` in math mode at the same level of the highest element (in `\displaystyle`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newsavebox{\mathbox}\newsavebox{\mathquote}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathquotes}[1]{% \mathquotes{<stuff>}
  \savebox{\mathquote}{\text{``}}% Save quotes
  \savebox{\mathbox}{$\displaystyle #1$}% Save <stuff>
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\mathbox-\ht\mathquote\relax}{``}#1\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\mathbox-\ht\mathquote\relax}{''}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[\text{``}\frac{1}{0^-}\text{''} \quad \mathquotes{\frac{1}{0^-}}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I cannot up vote your answer. Bur I would if I could.

Comment: @rpc: Thanks; [you need 15 reputation in order to up-vote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up). So you'll be there soon.